# Filter hundreds of coredumps by signal

Tags: core-dump, gdb

If I had several hundred core dumps in a directory and want to filter it down to just ones generated by a specific signal without having to manually open each one in GDB one at a time, is there a way to do that?

GDB does allow you to pass in commands via -ex flag, but GDB's output doesn't go the console, so i can't just run that on all the files and grep the results.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details why you think that "GDB's output doesn't go the console". On my Ubuntu system I can run e.g. `gdb program core < /dev/null |fgrep "Program terminated with signal"`.

Comment: I don't know, i don't know a lot of about linux Bodo, all i know is when i execute gdb the output from it isn't in my terminal. I'll take a look at that command you posted.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean with "when i execute gdb the output from it isn't in my terminal". Do you mean you don't see any output? Please copy&paste the command you use to call `gdb` and the resulting output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

I note you are using a conditional clause, so if the core dumps are not already generated, the easiest way is to include the signal in the name when they are generated. See `man 5 core` for details.

If you already have them, have a look at the details of the core format (see e.g. [here](https://www.gabriel.urdhr.fr/2015/05/29/core-file/)). I'd assume the signal number is in the various `siginfo_t` note entries (but didn't verify this), so extract them in whatever way is fast enough for you (custom C program if necessary), and filter for the signals you want.

Comment: This looks like enough to get me going. Thanks!